# How to get arguments string in a function?

Tags: python

In Python, is it possible to define a function `get_arg_str` that implements this:

```
def get_arg_str(arg):
    # do something here

mydict = {'key': 3}
str_arg = get_arg_str(mydict['key'])
# then str_arg should be string "mydict['key']"
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible because ``mydict['key']`` as an argument would simply pass the value held inside the dictionary at that key. The function accepting this argument would be completely unaware of how this value was passed to it.

Comment: You'd have to use something like `inspect.getsource()`.  In terms of execution, `get_arg_str(mydict['key'])` is completely indistinguishable from `get_arg_str(3)`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate what way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import sys

def get_arg_str(arg):
    n_line = sys._getframe().f_back.f_lineno
    filename = sys._getframe().f_back.f_code.co_filename
    funcname = sys._getframe().f_code.co_name
    code = open(filename).read()

    i_break = 0
    line_begin = -1
    for i in range(n_line):
        line_begin = i_break + 1
        i_break = code.find('\n', i_break+1)

    func_begin = code.find(funcname, line_begin) + len(funcname)
    left_brace = code.find('(', func_begin)
    right_brace = left_brace
    n_left_brace = 1
    while n_left_brace != 0:
        right_brace += 1
        if code[right_brace] == '(':
            n_left_brace += 1
        elif code[right_brace] == ')':
            n_left_brace -= 1

    return code[left_brace+1:right_brace].strip(" \t")

mydict = {'key': 3}
str_arg = get_arg_str(mydict['key'])
# now str_arg is string "mydict['key']"
```

Try it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible using introspection.

Something alone the lines of:

```
def get_arg_str(object, namespace):
    return [name for name in namespace if namespace[name] is object]


mydict = 'foo'
print(get_arg_str(mydict, globals()))
```

> `['mydict']`

You can build out from there using `string interpolation`.